# iOS - Property navigationController of UIViewController nil even though it's set as UINavigationController's rootViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am using storyboards to build my app's UI. Essentially, I am opening a `UINavigationController` as *modal* view, and in this navigation controller, I embed as `rootViewController` an instance of another `UIViewController` (*Location Selection View*). This is all set up in storyboard and looks basically like this:

[image]

Now, I want to access the navigation controller in the `viewDidLoad` of `LocationSelectionViewController` in order to include a `UISearchBar` in the navigation bar with:
`self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;`, this doesn't work however, because my `UINavigationController` is nil at this point, I know because I set a breakpoint and logged it:

`(lldb) po self.navigationController`

`nil`

Does anyone know why or what I have to do so that there is actually an instance of `UINavigationController` accessible on my `LocationSelectionViewController`?

UPDATE: Here is more code, the header really only consists of the declarations

**LocationSelectionViewController.h**

```
@protocol LocationSelectionViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)setLocation:(Location *)location;
@end

 @interface LocationSelectionViewController : UIViewController <GMSGeocodingServiceDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate>
 @end
```

**Parts of LocationSelectionViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.searchBar.text = DUMMY_ADDRESS;

  self.previouslySearchedLocations = [[CoreDataManager coreDataManagerSharedInstance] previouslySearchedLocations];
  self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.previouslySearchedLocations];

  self.mapView.delegate = self;
  self.gmsGeocodingService = [[GMSGeocodingService alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

  self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;
  }


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  [self addMapView];
}
```

Comment: Are you initialising LocationSelectionViewController programatically ?

Comment: Nope, it's instantiated by the storyboard. And there it is embedded into the `UINavigationController` via a _Relationship Segue_ of type type _root view_

Comment: And the `UINavigationController` is also instantiated by the storyboard. In the view controller who opens it as a _modal_ view, I looked in `prepareSegue` and can see that the `destinationViewController` of the `Segue` actually is a `UINavigatoinController`.

Comment: Destination viewController must be UINavigationController ,There is nothing wrong in that.

Comment: Yes, I know ;) that's what confuses me

Comment: Could you please provide a `LocationSelectionViewController.h` and part of `LocationSelectionViewController.m` with `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: I upated the post with my header (although there is really nothing much to see there) and `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:` of the implementation...

Comment: Are you calling performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" ?

Comment: Nope, as I set the segue right in the storyboard. And it's working after all, I am seeing the `LocationSelectionViewController` on screen! Only I can't access its `nagivationController` property which **should** be set as its embedded in one.

Comment: What is `self.searchDisplayController`?

Comment: I just done sample ,am getting navigationController as expected. Can you send your sample to me ??

Comment: @NikolayMamaev `(lldb) po self.searchDisplayController`
`<UISearchDisplayController: 0x16397970>`

Comment: @Yatheesha Sure, where should I send it to?

Comment: I also just created test project to reproduce this specific problem, in there it works fine...  My problem must lie somewhere else.

Comment: See my own answer to the post, it seems to be a bug in interface builder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I just solved my problem. I strongly believe it was a bug in interface builder. I deleted the old navigation controller and just dragged and dropped a new one onto the storyboard, now calling `po self.navigationController` in `viewDidLoad` actually returns an instance of `UINavigationController`. Thanks for all the help though, I appreciate it a lot!